# Trigger to update quantity if it falls below a certain number in MySql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to make a trigger to update the QTY column in my db_odetails table if the QTY falls below 5. 
Here is what I have so far, but I keep getting errors. 
drop trigger IF EXISTS qty_trigger;

```
DELIMITER ///

CREATE TRIGGER qty_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON db_odetails.QTY
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF select QTY from db_odetails < 5 THEN
        UPDATE db_odetails 
        SET db_odetails.QTY = 100 
        WHERE db_odetails.QTY < 5
        END IF;
    END;
///
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you edit with the error?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your trigger should look like this one:

```
DELIMITER ///
CREATE TRIGGER qty_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON db_odetails
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.qty) < 5 THEN
          SET NEW.qty=100;
        END IF;
    END;
///
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e34a3/1).